# Error retrieving image from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have image table in my sql database with three column name id, name and images.
when I try to retrieve the image it shows an error on the first line:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I want to see the name of image in the dropdownlist and image in image control.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True");
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from image where name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {

                string image1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                byte[] bimage1 = (byte[])dr["name"];
                fs1.Write(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length - 1);
                fs1.Flush();
                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Image1.Visible = true;
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from image where name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);

Comment: Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Image1.Visible = true;  // change Image1 to image1

Comment: but first the sql command is showing the error not the image control....

Comment: `Image1` is probably his image control and `image1` is a local string. So thats not the problem

Comment: yes jordy van eijk...u r correct....problem is in sqlcommand....did i make anymistake?

Comment: Is this the data of the image `(byte[])dr["name"];`?

Comment: what is the value of  con in this line? can u pls tell?

Comment: (byte[])dr["name"]....not it is not the data of image...it the name given to image

Comment: con value will be the connection string value

Comment: @user1466706 I hope your problem has been solved if not then please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18786970/1230248

Answer (score 1):

If you get a NullReferenceException on your SqlCommand line than your DropDownList1.SelectedItem is probably null. And calling ToString on a null object gives this NullReferenceException Please try and debug your program and hover over your SelectedItem to see if its null

Comment: yes i have debug the program...in the selecteditem of dropdownlist box is showing null....so what would be problem?

Comment: If the SelectedItem of your DropDownList is null then you probably didn't select an item in the DropDownList. This will end yo in the null reference. Because this code is in the Page_Load you cant have it selected. Better is to have a selectionchanged event on your DropDownList to and then select your images from your table.

Comment: Jordy van eijk....i have put entire code inside the selectindexchange event of dropdownlist...so now when i run the page it show me with error that "Control 'DropDownList1' of type 'DropDownList' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. "...what to do?

Comment: Just what it says. You need to place your dropdownlist inside a html Form tag and give the tag the attribute runat="server"

Answer (score 1):

you should change the code :

var index= DropDownList1.SelectedItem!=null?DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString():defaultitem;

then in that query u can use index.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something quite strange here. Looks like you are attempting to write an image to disk, but the bytes you specified are casted from the name column?

```
byte[] bimage1 = (byte[])dr["name"];
fs1.Write(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length - 1);
```

if the url of the image is saved in the database you need to use WebClient to first download the bytes of the image before you can write the image out. It also looks like you are trying to show the image by assigning the url to Image control. However the exception is probably because there was no selected item in your dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace follwoing

```
 SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from image where name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
```

to

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from image where name='" + Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) + "'", con);
```

this might not give you the record you expect but it wont give you error .. try it!!